# Javascript regex to catch either '%20' or whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

Can't get my head around regex. Want to turn this string:

```
 var str = "Hello my%20name is%20Jascination"
```

into

```
 str2 = "Hello&my&name&is&Jascination"
```

I've tried:

```
 var str2 = str.replace(/[20%]/w/s/g, '&')
 var str2 = str.replace(/[20%/w/s]/g, '&')
```

but these don't work. With Regex how do I capture both specific characters and specific groups of characters?

Comment: Did you mean to target `20%` in the regex, not `%20`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy. Just use or ([x|y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or))

```
var str2 = str.replace(/%20| /g, '&');
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3V6Bmm_iyxEWoyjX)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str2 = str.replace(/(?:%20|\s)+/g, '&');
```

Comment: @jfriend00: `(?:..)`is a non capturing group, because you don't need to capture anything! You avoid this work for the regex engine.

Comment: But, it's a global replace operation. Nothing is being captured here and you're only applying it to the `%20`, not to the `\s` which confuses also.  Also doesn't seem like you need the `+` either as the OP didn't ask to multiple consecutive spaces or `%20` to a single `&`.

Comment: @jfriend00: indeed, but my pattern supports several back to back white spaces or `%20`, thus I must put these in a group to repeat it with the `+` quantifier. (and avoiding consecutive &&& in the result)

Comment: OK, except the OP didn't ask for that.  Just wondering what benefits your more complicated answer provides over the sectus answer.

Comment: @jfriend00: OP (in general) is frequently stopped in his reflexion by a technical problem and doesn't see futur other problems. However, it's not a complicated pattern.